# What should be more performant in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, performance

I was wondering what would be more performant. Native functions of the language that implies 2 iterations or a simple `for` loop.

The idea is to find the index of an array of objects whose property filterId match a concrete value.

The solution with a `for` would be this one whose runtime is n

```
 for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        if (entries[i].filterId === filterId) {
            return i;
        }
    }
```

or this other solution which internally must use 2 loops one for the `map` and another one for the `indexOf`. However, these are JS functions which are optimized internally by the JS engine. runtime 2n.

```
   entries.map(item=>item.filterId).indexOf(filterId);
```

some enlightenment about this?

Comment: You could just... test it?

Comment: http://jsben.ch/

use this to see which is quicker.

Comment: Is your array greater than, say, 10000 entries? Don't worry, both versions are fast enough. Even if not, there are ways around this which do not impede readability.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

```
entries.findIndex(item => item.filterId === filterId)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make it using widely available array capabilities and still have a complexity of O(n).

For instance you can use`array.some`.
Advantage of `array.some` : it is available in almost all browsers, (available in IE since IE9).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some for documentation

```js
const data = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}]

let foundIndex = null;
data.some((value, index) => {
    if(value.id === 3) {
      foundIndex = index;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
});

console.log(foundIndex);
```